# How do I copy an HICON from GDI to GDI+ with transparency?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, transparency, gdi+, gdi

No matter what I do, I get white/black borders around the icon... what gives?!

Is it even *possible* to do this correctly? How do I copy an HICON to a GDI+ Bitmap with transparency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wasted several hours on it.

Combined with how much I'd wasted many times before, yes, it's frustrating.

Turns out it's a problem with GDI+. A workaround is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120201182215/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97232/graphics-drawicon-will-not-render-alpha-icon-correctly-when-graphics-is-a-bitmap); here's some code that might help:

```
HICON hIcon = ...;

ICONINFO ii; GetIconInfo(hIcon, &ii);
BITMAP bmp; GetObject(ii.hbmColor, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);

Gdiplus::Bitmap temp(ii.hbmColor, NULL);
Gdiplus::BitmapData lockedBitmapData;
Gdiplus::Rect rc(0, 0, temp.GetWidth(), temp.GetHeight());

temp.LockBits(&rc, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, temp.GetPixelFormat(), &lockedBitmapData);

Gdiplus::Bitmap image(
    lockedBitmapData.Width, lockedBitmapData.Height, lockedBitmapData.Stride,
    PixelFormat32bppARGB, reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(lockedBitmapData.Scan0));

temp.UnlockBits(&lockedBitmapData);

// Now 'image' has the icon, with transparency
```

Comment: Many thanks. I was suffering the same problem of the black lines. I tried your solution and had another problem: some lines and pixels were missing. I tried to use BITMAPs and adapt this code to them, and now the images are rendered perfectly!

Comment: @hackjutsu: I believe it was supposed to be `lockedBitmapData`.